# Blob image url to php not working

Tags: php, jquery

This is my first time trying to deal with blob data.

I'm trying to send the blob image url via ajax to php for uploading the icon but it's not working, I am not sure if I'm even doing it correctly, can someone help me out?

```
console.log(apk.app.icon_url); // Prints: blob:http://localhost/9ca5a837-fdb4-4288-a21a-18e9650e6ac5

let data = new FormData();

data.append('icon', apk.app.icon_url);

$.ajax({
    url: "testicon.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data); // PHP array returns empty
    }
});
```

Comment: If that's what's shown, then `apk.app.icon_url` is a string, not a blob.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Is there any possibility that I can at least view the image with html or something like that using this url?

Comment: Sorry for double comment, but I just realized that I also have apk.iconBlob which prints Blob(30795) {size: 30795, type: ""}

Comment: That's the one you want. `append()` that for your `FormData` and see what happens.

Comment: Yup, I just tried that and it worked. Just didn't have the idea that I've been using blob url instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working